# Code fix : change members and class being used for a method call

Tags: c#, visual-studio, static-code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis, codefixprovider

I am doing a code analyser but I can't find a way to change the class and the members being accessed when you are calling a method. For example if i have

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public static void DoSomething(object SomeParameter)
    {
        //method body 
    }
}
public class SecondClass
{
    public static void ReplaceDoSomething(object SomeParameter)
    {
        //other method's body
    }
}
```

How could i make my code fix change `FirstClass.DoSomething(new object());` to `SecondClass.ReplaceDoSomething(new object());`?

I tried to use `SyntaxFactory` but i can't realy figure out what parameters are expected for most methods and the MSDN provides nearly no details on them...

**The code analyzer**

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterOperationAction(Analyze, OperationKind.Invocation);
}
private void Analyze(OperationAnalysisContext context)
{
    IInvocationOperation operation = (IInvocationOperation)context.Operation;
    if (operation.TargetMethod.Name == "DoSomething" && operation.TargetMethod.ContainingNamespace.Name == "FirstNamespace" && operation.TargetMethod.ContainingType.Inherits("FirstNamespace.FirstClass"))
    {
        //Rule is an automaticaly generated variable by visual studio when you create the analyzer
        Diagnostic diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, operation.Syntax.GetLocation());
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
}
public static class INamedTypeSymbolExtensions
{
    public static bool Inherits(this INamedTypeSymbol first, string otherFullName)
    {
        if (first.GetFullName() == otherFullName)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (typeof(object).FullName == first.GetFullName())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return first.BaseType.Inherits(otherFullName);
        }
    }

    public static string GetFullName(this INamedTypeSymbol element)
    {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(element.Name);
        INamespaceSymbol ContainingNamespace = element.ContainingNamespace;
        while (ContainingNamespace.ContainingNamespace != null)
        {
            ret.Insert(0, ContainingNamespace.Name + ".");
            ContainingNamespace = ContainingNamespace.ContainingNamespace;
        }
        return ret.ToString();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : The best result i have had was with

```
private async Task<Document> ProvideCodeFix(Document document, InvocationExpressionSyntax invocation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    SyntaxToken replaced = invocation.GetFirstToken();
    SyntaxToken replacing = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("SecondClass").GetFirstToken().WithLeadingTrivia(replaced.LeadingTrivia));
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot((await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync()).ReplaceToken(replaced, replacing);
}
```

with this it would change `FirstClass.DoSomething(new object());` to `SecondClass.DoSomething(new object());`

But the main problem with this approach is that if i'd have to change `FirstNamespace.FirstClass.DoSomething(new object());` to `SecondClass.ReplaceDoSomething(new object());` then it'd not work

PS : I use `.WithLeadingTrivia(...)` to keep the comments and such stuff that was written before `FirstClass`

Comment: I tried to use loads of methods mostly `.WithSomething(...)` or `.ReplaceSomething(...)` so i can't realy write them all so i wrote the most successful result i have had for now @NineBerry

Comment: @NineBerry are you talking about the code that calls `ProvideCodeFix(...)`?

Comment: ah the analyzer, it works fine and underlines correctly, both are quite independant anyways aren't them? (i mean expect the expression being underlined and its location)

Comment: hmmm yeah from this point of view that's right, i had made the (wrong) assumption that people would probably not need to test it as this question isn't that advanced. Give me enough time and i'll add the analyzer.

Comment: The code that registers `ProvideCodeFix`is still missing

Comment: it's been auto generated too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works. We get the `InvocationExpressionSyntax.Expression` which represents the whole part before the `()` argument list. Then we replace that whole expression.

```
private async Task<Document> ProvideCodeFix(Document document, InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Get the expression that represents the entity that the invocation happens on
    // (In this case this is the method name including possible class name, namespace, etc)
    var invokedExpression = invocationExpression.Expression;

    // Construct an expression for the new classname and methodname
    var classNameSyntax = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("SecondClass");
    var methodNameSyntax = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("ReplaceDoSomething");
    var classNameAndMethodNameSyntax = SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression, classNameSyntax, methodNameSyntax);

    // Add the surrounding trivia from the original expression
    var replaced = classNameAndMethodNameSyntax;
    replaced = replaced.WithLeadingTrivia(invokedExpression.GetLeadingTrivia());
    replaced = replaced.WithTrailingTrivia(invokedExpression.GetTrailingTrivia());

    // Replace the whole original expression with the new expression
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot((await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync()).ReplaceNode(invokedExpression, replaced));
}
```

Comment: It works alright except when you have comments between `FirstClass` and `DoSomething` for example `FirstClass./*wierd comment*/DoSomething(new object());` will be changed to `SecondClass.ReplaceDoSomething(new object());` anyways your answer is enough to me, thanks

Comment: @nalka Keeping such comments requires a bit more code and is a bit more complex because the `invokedExpression` can be different types of syntaxes (a simple `IdentifierNameSyntax` or a `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax` in several varieties). But it can be done. I think what you should take away from my answer is to work with SyntaxNodes instead of on the token level.